# Jquery datatable PageLength does not do anything on select list change

Tags: jquery, datatable, codeigniter-3

I am using jquery datatable and when I change the number of rows from the dropdown list of datatable from 20 - 50. It does not show me the remaining rows.

I have tried changing different attributes but none of them worked for me.

```
$('#eventsTable').dataTable( {
    "aaSorting": [],
    "iDisplayLength": 20,
    "aLengthMenu": [[20, 50, -1], [20, 50, "All"]],

} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try given solution

```
$("#urTable").dataTables({ 
    "bJQueryUI":true, 
    "bSort":false, 
    "bPaginate":true,      
    "sPaginationType":"full_numbers", 
    "iDisplayLength": 10 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$('#myTable').dataTable( {
   "pageLength": 25,
   "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"] ]
});
```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/unx70jwa/)